# Windows Server 2012 DHCP not working sometimes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, ip, dhcp, autoconfiguration

Currently on my network I have Windows Server 2012 setup with DNS, DHCP, and Squid Proxy. Most of the time when my clients connect to the network the DHCP server won't hand them an IP address, leaving them with an auto-configured address 169.254.x.x . What am I doing wrong? Google searching shows that auto-configuration only happens when the device can't find a DHCP server, but the server has a static IP already from the router.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail from you about your configuration and about what troubleshooting steps you've taken so far.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for the reply. Could you go more into detail on what I'll need to provide to solve this issue? For troubleshooting, I've looked into making sure that the router DHCP has been turned off, made sure that my scope hasn't filled up (About 30 spots left) and to make sure the correct gateway is provided.

Comment: At that point a network trace can be usefull. Dhcp negociation happen in broadcast, thus something can block it easilly. Please capture some packet to try to isolate the problem (wireshark)

Answer (score 0):

You may be out of DHCP address space and some of the clients will be unable to be assigned an address.
How many terminals/PCs do you have and what class of IP addresses (example: 192.168.1.0) ? 
Also, make sure you set a proper lease value, so IPs unused for a long time are un-allocated.

Comment: Like I said, I already checked to see if the scope ran out of IP addresses (Which its not). Also, changing the lease value didn't help. Mostly happens when I device reconnects where it auto configures, not when it first connects to the next work. The only solution I've found was to give each device a static IP.

Comment: Maybe DHCP Authorization self-repeats, since that is a one-time procedure, you server may be wrongly configured. Remove DHCP and reinstall it again by following the procedures described in Technet.